# Android Custom Pinyin Keyboard

Tags: android, android-custom-keyboard

I have implemented a custom pinyin keyboard for android and I don't know why it always shows:

```
keyboardcustom_inputmethod_pinyin_PinyinDecoderService.cpp:130: jstring nativeImGetPyStr(JNIEnv *, jclass, jboolean): assertion "py != NULL" failed
04-04 08:15:17.061 27163-27163/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 27163 (.keyboardcustom)
```

Can somebody help?